# A question about de Sitter-invariant general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, de-sitter-spacetime

In the case of standard general relativity, all solutions to the gravitational field equations are spacetimes that reduce locally to Minkowski. Einstein’s equation is written as
$R^{\mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}R=-8\pi T^{\mu\nu}.$
In the case of the de Sitter-invariant general relativity, all solutions to the gravitational field equation are spacetimes that reduce locally to de Sitter. The de Sitter-invariant Einstein’s equation is written as
$R^{\mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}R=-8\pi \Pi^{\mu\nu},$
where the source current $\Pi^{\mu\nu}$ splits in the form
$$\Pi^{\mu\nu}=T^{\mu\nu}-\frac{1}{4l^2}K^{\mu\nu}.$$
$T^{\mu\nu}$ is energy-momentum and $K^{\mu\nu}$ is proper conformal current. These sources satisfy
$$T^{\mu\nu}=\delta^\mu_\alpha T^{\alpha\nu}, ~\Pi^{\mu\nu}=\xi^\mu_\alpha T^{\alpha\nu} and ~K^{\mu\nu}=\theta^\mu_\alpha T^{\alpha\nu},$$
where $\delta^\mu_\alpha$ is the killing vectors of the Minkoeski translations, $\xi^\mu_\alpha$ is the killing vectors of the de Sitter translations and $\theta^\mu_\alpha=2\eta_{\alpha\beta}x^\beta x^\mu-\sigma^2 \delta^\mu_\alpha.$ The details were showed in section 4 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.09075#:%7E:text=An%20Improved%20Framework%20for%20Quantum%20Gravity%20J.%20G.,gravitational%20variable%20representing%20gravitation%20only%2C%20inertial%20forces%20apart.).

In 4.3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.08108v1), a de Sitter-invariant black hole solution was found. In this spacetims, $T^\mu_\nu=0$ and $K^\mu_\nu\neq 0$. But I think $T^\mu_\nu=0$ must lead to $K^\mu_\nu=0$ according to $K^{\mu\nu}=\theta^\mu_\alpha T^{\alpha\nu}$. So why does this contradiction arise? What is the relaionship between $T^{\mu\nu}$ and $K^{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: Skimming the papers I see other strange things. In particular they claim that instead of a repulsive force proportional to distance in de Sitter space, there's a *constant* force (eq. 56 of the second paper you linked, and eq. 64 of [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02120)), which would have to be directed toward a privileged center of the universe, but they also claim the spacetime is homogeneous. I think it's a physically nonsensical model dressed up in fancy language.